# C++ Netbeans cout error

Tags: netbeans

I never had these errors in dev C++. When i use cout in Netbeans its giving me no match for operator error.
This is my program

`#include <cstdlib>`
#`include <fstream>`
#include `<iostream>`
  using namespace std;

int main()
{
   //read file
   fstream fileStream;
   string tempStr;
   string strText;
   fileStream.open("fincode.htm", ios::in);
   while(!fileStream.eof())
   {
     fileStream >> tempStr;
     strText += tempStr;
     cout >> strText;
   }

```
fileStream.close();
return 0;
```

}

I get the following errors when i build it

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/NetBeansProjects/read_page2'
main.cpp:31: error: no match for ‘operator>>’ in ‘std::cout >> strText’
make[2]: * [build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o] Error 1
make[1]: * [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

I dont get any errors if i remove cout. Any idea whats going on?

Comment: Sorry! that was a silly error on my part. Works fine when i change >> to <<. Thank you, its working now.

Answer (score 2):

You need:

```
#include <string>
```

Also, your while-loop is wrong - you should not normally use the eof() function as a loop control - use:

```
  while( fileStream >> tempStr )
   {
     strText += tempStr;
     cout << strText;      // note operator <<
   }
```

And I just noticed that your cout statement was incorrect too.

Comment: @Graham Consider what happens if the file is empty. eof() only works AFTER you have tried to read something.

Comment: Thanks. i was using the wrong operator for cout. It works now. Good point with the eof(). I've made changes to the while statement too.

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
#include <string>
```

And change

```
cout >> strText;
```

To

```
cout << strText;
```

Comment: There was no need for #include <string>